# Update Multiple Values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am trying to update multiple values in the database. However, I am only able to update one value at a time when the Submit button is clicked.

NOTE:- I just need to know how to iterate through the $_POST variables without having to hard code them and pass them into the function if it is not NULL.

Any advice on how I could get this to submit for multiple fields.

HTML:-

```
    First Name :
        <input type="text" name="CUSTOMER_FNAME" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['CUSTOMER_FNAME'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['CUSTOMER_FNAME']); ?>" 
          placeholder="<?php echo $customerRegistration->property('CUSTOMER_FNAME');?>" />
    LastName:   
        <input type="text" name="CUSTOMER_LNAME" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['CUSTOMER_LNAME'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['CUSTOMER_LNAME']); ?>" 
          placeholder="<?php echo $customerRegistration->property('CUSTOMER_LNAME');?>" />
    Email:
        <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['EMAIL'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['EMAIL']); ?>" 
          placeholder="<?php echo $customerRegistration->property('EMAIL');?>" />
```

The function is here:-

```
$id= $_SESSION['id'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ($value!= NULL && $key!="submit") {
            $customerRegistration->update_one($id,$key,$value); 
        }
    }   
}


  public function update_one($id,$key,$value){
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$value)

    $sql  = "UPDATE `customer_registration` SET ";
    $sql .= "`{$key}`="."'{$value}' ";
    $sql .= "WHERE `CUSTOMER_ID`="."'{$id}' ";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}
```

Note:- $customerRegistration is an instance of class Customer Registration which has access to the update_one($id, $key,$value) method and that updates fine for single values.

I just need to know how can the loop in the $_POST variable keep running as long it is not empty(multiple values are edited.)

Result of Var Dump:-

```
      array(6) { ["CUSTOMER_FNAME"]=> string(4) "UMAR" ["CUSTOMER_LNAME"]=> string(5) "AFTAB" ["EMAIL"]=> string(16) "abcd@hotmail.com" ["PHONE"]=> string(10) "4154561235" ["CUSTOMER_DOB"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(14) "Submit Changes" }
```

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what `$customerRegistration` is an instance of.

Comment: run a var_dump in your $_POST and see if all the desired values are there

Comment: @wogsland but the update function is working fine though

Comment: @PhiterFernandes They are ...

Comment: My issue is to loop over them

Comment: What if you use if instead of while?

Comment: write a `update_many`, instead of using `update_one`

Comment: @Dragon
Can you give me an idea.. I will edit the question and add the update_one query

Comment: Umar, update the question with the code inside update_one

Comment: @PhiterFernandes..Added the update_one query

Comment: I just need to know how to iterate through the $_POST variables without having to hard code them and pass them into the function if the value in the textbox has been changed,

Comment: With the if() instead of while the looping part is ok. The problem is somewhere else in the code. Print out the $key - $value pairs within the foreach loop to see if the loop works.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I added the result of var dump in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop becomes an endless loop, if any of the parameters are set. Replace the while loop with a simple if(). $value variable cannot ever be null, max empty string, so remove that condition from the if:

```
    if ($key!="submit") {
        $customerRegistration->update_one($id,$key,$value); 
    }
```

Comment: That does not work, I changed from if to while, appreciate the effort though.

Comment: The "does not work" is a meaningless response. Pls provide exact error message or describe the unexpected behaviour!

Comment: I tried that before switching to while. the if only updates one value and allows only one update

Comment: But now it ignores the fact that null values are being submitted, which will replace the original value with null value.

Comment: You cannot submit a php null value through an html form. You are mixing up stuff. There is no error handling in your update code. Why?

Comment: Thats in a separate function in a different file, and that is not my question. There is no NULL submission. Read the Question it says I need assitsance in iterating !

Comment: Read the answers and comments first. There is nothing wrong with the loop if you use if(). But if you omit important parts of the code, then how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: What do you need me to show you from the code...because this is quite frustrating..

Comment: I cannot guess what is in your code. As wrote earlier in a comment: print out the $key - $value pairs within the foreach loop to se how the loop works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100329/discussion-between-umar-aftab-and-shadow).

Comment: If you cannot or are unwilling to debug your code, then we cannot help you. Wrote several times to print out the foreach loop and add error handling to your db code.

Comment: Ok let me get back to you with error handling in the code and the foreach loop result. I will update the question.

Comment: Added erro chcking as well

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, if you're using PHP 5.6 you can use variadic. See the link below. Hope this helps. :)

https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2013/08/30/potential-variadic-function-syntax-for-php-56/

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    function update_one($id, $_POST);

}


function update_one($id, ...$params)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `customer_registration` SET ";
    foreach ($params as $key => $val){
        if ($value != NULL && $key != "submit") { 
            $sql.= "`{$key}`="."'{$value}' ";
        }
    }
    $sql.= "WHERE `CUSTOMER_ID`="."'{$id}' ";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}
```

Comment: would you be able to illustrate how that will help me in iterating through the $_POST variables.

Comment: see the update, it's not tested. i hope you get the idea

Comment: Do not mix arrays with variable number of parameters. You do not need variadic approach here, since you simply pass the $_POST array as parameter.

Comment: @Shadow yes, i agree with you but if he wanted to pass multiple specific  parameters then variadics would be ideal. Anyway it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the name of inputs in $_POST. That's what it is for

```
$id= $_SESSION['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$input_names = ['CUSTOMER_FNAME', 'CUSTOMER_LNAME', 'EMAIL'];
  for($i=0;$i<count($input_names);$i++){
    foreach ($_POST[$input_names][$i] as $key => $value) {
      if ($value!= NULL && $key!="submit") {
        $customerRegistration->update_one($id,$key,$value); 
      } // end of if
    }  // end of foreach
  } // end of for

} // end of if
```

Comment: For this to work the field names in html should be changed to include a trailing []. But the question does not indicate that multiple records are updated.

Comment: $_POST[$input_names[$i]] = $_POST['CUSTOM_FNAME']. What you are saying would be true if i put the $i behind $_POST, like this: $_POST[$input_names][$i]. I loop trough the array of names.

Comment: foreach ($_POST[$input_names[$i]] as $key => $value) loop implies that you believe that each input name occures multiple times in the post.

Comment: ye sry :D 3:30 AM, so the correct one is $_POST[$input_names][$i].

Comment: or maybe that for loop is even useless here, all he needs to do is do foreach($_POST[$input_names] as $key => $value)

Comment: I do not think there is anything wrong with the foreach loop in the OP.

Comment: :D ook, I see you are good at MySQL, maybe you could help with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713014/multiple-table-join-mysql-multiple-foreign-keys/34713077#34713077

Comment: @Shadow is right, that loop checks the post variable multiple times and returns Undefined index error