# Multiple table join MySQL multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having difficult times with joins in MySQL. I have 4 tables, all connected together.

```
**Order**: order_id, shop_id(fk), date, day, order_price, PK_order
**Scan** : scan_id(PK), item_id, order_id(FK), stack, stack_price, price, note
**Item** : item_id(PK), item_name
**Shop** : shop_id(PK), shop_name
```

I want to build a query that outputs something like this:

```
date|day|shop_name|item_name|stack|stack_price|price|note
```

My query looks like this:

```
Select
      order.date, order.day, shop.shop_name, item.item_name, scan.stack, scan.stack_price,
      scan.price, scan.note
From
      order, scan, shop, item
Join
      shop on order.shop_id = shop.shop_id
Join
      item on scan.item_id = item.item_id
```

I get error 1054: Unknown column ... in 'on clause', or the other 'alias' error.

However when I select only one column from one table, i get it working.
This query works:

```
 select item.item_name from scan inner join item on scan.item_id = item.item_id
```

I think there is some problem with selecting from multiple tables... Anyone can help me? Every reply is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The word `order` is special in MySQL, so it's a good idea to put ticks around it unless you're doing an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: despite Vr46 answer is correct - i think - rethink the name "order" as a table name as wogsland mentioned - "order" will make troubles in any sql , you would not call a table "where", or "select" would you?

Comment: I actually don't use that word in my project, I just translated it to english from my native language just so you could understand :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have combined *comma separated join* and *Inner join* where you have used same table more than once which is not needed.

If am not wrong this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT `order`.`DATE`, 
       `order`.`day`, 
       shop.shop_name, 
       item.item_name, 
       scan.stack, 
       scan.stack_price, 
       scan.price, 
       scan.note 
FROM   `order` 
       join scan 
         ON `order`.order_id = scan.order_id 
       join shop 
         ON `order`.shop_id = shop.shop_id 
       join item 
         ON scan.item_id = item.item_id
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but I get empty set back :D I have to rethink my logic